# How do I transfer a python list to a csv table?

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I sent a request to a website and then parsed it. Got a list but have issues making it a csv file table. When I try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv


website = requests.get("https://www.tradingview.com/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-all/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(website.text, 'lxml')

name = soup.find_all('a', class_ ="tv-screener__symbol")

with open('newparser.csv', 'w') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(name)
```

It prints out:

```
"<a class=""tv-screener__symbol"" href=""/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-cryptoxtvcbtc/"" target=""_blank"">Bitcoin</a>","<a class=""tv-screener__symbol"" href=""/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-cryptoxtvceth/"" target=""_blank"">Ethereum</a>","<a class=""tv-screener__symbol"" href=""/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-cryptoxtvcbnb/"" target=""_blank"">Binance Coin</a>","<a class=""tv-screener__symbol"" href=""/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-cryptoxtvcada/"" target=""_blank"">Cardano</a>","<a class=""tv-screener__symbol"" href=""/markets/cryptocurrencies/prices-cryptoxtvcusdt/"
```

Not going to post the whole thing but you get the point.

When I change:

```
wr.writerow(name) --> wr.writerow(name.text)
```

It prints out:

> ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a
> list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when
> you meant to call find()?

And when I make a loop:

```
for i in name:
    wr.writerow(i.text)
```

It creates a file like this:

> "B","i","t","c","o","i","n"
>
> "E","t","h","e","r","e","u","m"
>
> "B","i","n","a","n","c","e"," ","C","o","i","n"
>
> "C","a","r","d","a","n","o"
>
> "T","e","t","h","e","r"
>
> "H","E","X"
>
> "X","R","P"
>
> "S","o","l","a","n","a"
>
> "D","o","g","e","c","o","i","n"
>
> "U","S","D"," ","C","o","i","n"
>
> "P","o","l","k","a","d","o","t"
>
> "T","e","r","r","a"
>
> "U","n","i","s","w","a","p"

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`writerow` takes an iterable to columns.

Strings are iterable, causing each character to be put into columns

If you want to write a single value, then put a list around the value

```
for i in name:
    writer.writerow([i.text])
```